# Retrieving the original files from "git-lfs" files in a repository

Tags: git, repository, git-lfs

I found a git repository with a bunch of *.png files that I need.

The files' raw format however uses the git lfs and look like this:

```
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid 
sha256:82247bedcaf9f441851f272ca2213a64b1b1084b13709eee02f185921b057efe
size 258233
```

I've tried cloning the repository to view the images but I get the following:

```
error: external filter 'git-lfs filter-process' failed
fatal: "file_name".png: smudge filter lfs failed
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
```

The "git pull" command returns the same error:

```
error: external filter 'git-lfs filter-process' failed
fatal: "file_name".png: smudge filter lfs failed.
```

The "git lfs pull" command simply returns "could not pull".

I ultimately want to view the "file_name".png as an image file instead of the sha256 string.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include the output of `git rev-parse HEAD --symbolic-full-name HEAD` and `GIT_TRACE=1 git lfs checkout`?

Comment: The first command returns `fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.` The GIT_TRACE is not recognized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your repository seems to be in a bad state. You're missing the `HEAD` revision, which is present in all Git repositories with at least one commit. `git lfs pull` and most other Git LFS commands won't work in a repository without commits, which is why you're getting that error.

It also sounds like you're on Windows, due to the lack of sensible shell variable handling. I'd recommend re-cloning your repository in Git Bash, and if you still have a problem, try running the clone (again in Git Bash) with a `GIT_TRACE=1` in front of it, which should help explain what's going on.

Do note that if the repository literally contains files with double-quotes in the name, those files won't work in Windows, since Windows doesn't permit file paths to contain double quotes.

Comment: I used the Git Bash along with a `GIT_TRACE=1` pull but I got `Git can't resolve ref: "Head"`. The `GIT_TRACE=1` lfs pull returns the same smudge filter error.

Comment: The log returns the following: Error downloading... Smudge error
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors.newWrappedError
        C:/Users/brian m. carlson/checkouts/git-lfs/errors/types.go:198github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/commands.Run
        C:/Users/brian m. carlson/checkouts/git-lfs/commands/run.go:97
main.main
        C:/Users/brian m. carlson/checkouts/git-lfs/git-lfs.go:33
runtime.main
        C:/Go/src/runtime/proc.go:201
runtime.goexit
        C:/Go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1333

Comment: Yeah, as mentioned, your repository is either broken or doesn't have any commits if you can't resolve `HEAD`. That's not a Git or Git LFS problem, that's definitely a repository problem.